# Skip spaces in string during loop, Assembly palindrome

Tags: assembly, x86, label, nasm, palindrome

I'm trying to do a palindrome checker program and I'm stuck in skipping spaces in string. It works with single words but not with sentences.
I've tried to add a *skip_space1* and *skip_space2* but it doesn't work with spaces.

Code:

```
         call getaddr  ; push on the stack the runtime address of format and jump to getaddr
format   db "evil olive"
length   equ $ - format
         db 0xA, 0

getaddr:
         mov ecx, length  ; ecx = length

         shr ecx, 1  ; ecx = ecx >> 1 = ecx / 2

         jecxz pass  ; jump if ecx is zero ; jump if ecx = 0

         mov esi, [esp]           ; esi = *(int*)esp = format
         lea edi, [esi+length-1]  ; edi = esi + length - 1

.loop    mov al, [esi]  ; al = *(char*)esi
         mov ah, [edi]  ; ah = *(char*)edi
         
         cmp al, ' '
         je skip_space1

         cmp ah, ' '
         je skip_space2

         cmp al, ah
         jne not_pass

         inc esi  ; esi++
         dec edi  ; edi--

         loop .loop

pass:
...
         
skip_space2:
         dec edi
         jmp .loop

skip_space1:
         inc esi
         jmp .loop
```

When I try add `jmp .loop` at the end of skip statements it returns:

> palindrom0.asm:61: error: symbol skip_space2.loop not defined

> palindrom0.asm:65: error: symbol `skip_space1.loop' not defined

Comment: Well, you'll need to jump back from your two skip statements to where you came from, i.e. `cmp al` and `cmp ah` respectively. You'll need to also reload each of those two registers, as appropriate.

Comment: when I try to add jmp .loop in skip statements it returns : "error: symbol `skip_space2.loop' not defined
error: symbol `skip_space1.loop' not defined"

Comment: Add your code exactly as it stands now. I'm not familiar with `nasm` - hopefully someone who is will jump in - but in the meantime, the error suggests that the dot in `.loop` makes it a local label, so you may want to take the dots out.

Comment: Ok, I change .loop to loop1 and it works. But another problem: when I use upper case instead only lower case it doesnt work. How to handle it?

Comment: Do you mean you want upper and lower case letters to compare equal? For the ASCII range of letters, converting from one case to the other is done by adding or subtracting 0x20.

Comment: A [local label in nasm](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-local-label.html) is a label that is associated with the previous non-local label. `.loop` was local to `getaddr`, using it in `skip_space2` makes nasm look for a `.loop` that is associated with `skip_space2` but there is no `.loop` there. There are various ways to fix the problem that you were having with it.

Answer (score 1):

Labels that start with a dot are local labels to NASM. They are valid between any two normal aka global labels. Because you had the global labels *pass:*, *skip_space2:*, and *skip_space1:*, the local label *.loop* before them was not accessible. The clearest solution is to declare all these labels to be local to *getaddr:*, so *.loop:*, *.pass:*, *.skip_space2:*, and *.skip_space1:*.

Working with a count in ECX is far from ideal in this task because each time that skipping a space is needed, you'll need to recalculate the count. And anyway, you should never be using the `loop` instruction in 32-bit code because it's a slow instruction.
Just setup pointers to the first and last characters, and continu the loop for as long as the low pointer is below the high pointer.

### Suggestion (untested)

```
getaddr:
  mov   esi, [esp]           ; points at first char
  lea   edi, [esi+length-1]  ; points at last char
.loopA:
  cmp   esi, edi
  jnb   .pass
  movzx eax, byte [esi]
  inc   esi
  cmp   al, ' '
  je    .loopA

.loopB:
  cmp   esi, edi
  jnbe  .pass
  movzx edx, byte [edi]
  dec   edi
  cmp   dl, ' '
  je    .loopB

  cmp   al, dl
  je    .loopA

.not_pass:
  ...

.pass:
  ...
```

If the string apart from spaces and [a,z], also could contain [A,Z], then you can have it work case-insensitive by adding next to the code:

```
  or    eax, 32    ; turns [A,Z] into [a,z]
  or    edx, 32    ; dito
  cmp   al, dl
  je    .loopA
```

Comment: Forcing both to lower-case is probably the easiest to understand.  (And works without further checking if you can assume the string only has alphabetic or space characters, otherwise setting that bit could turn one non-letter into a different non-letter, like `'@'` into ```'`'``` (backtick).)  But as a fun optimization, we can do the same check with `xor eax, edx` / `test al, ~0x20` / `jz` to check that all bits except the lower-case bit matched, branching the same way as the somewhat more intuitive `(AL|0x20 == DL|0x20)` for every input I think. It loses the opportunity to check for a letter.